# How to replace images in iPhoto with higher quality versions?

Tags: applescript, photos.app, aperture

I use Aperture for photo editing and processing, but prefer iPhoto for keeping a gallery of my pictures. For a long time, I used the built-in tools in iPhoto to "Import from Aperture Library". What I didn't know was that this only imports the preview image, which is at a quarter resolution and badly compressed. I now have a couple of years worth of albums with lots of metadata but crappy image quality. I'd like to replace the images with higher-quality versions from Aperture, without losing all of the metadata (tags, descriptions, faces, etc). What's the easiest way to do this?

Related question: is it possible to access/change the image data in iPhoto with AppleScript? I can write a script to match images and replace them, if there's a mechanism to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I eventually solved this problem. It took a few steps, and requires some scripting and command line hackery, but it did the trick.

1. Export the pictures you want to update from Aperture to a folder, say `~/Pictures/Updates`
2. Open the album in iPhoto
3. Use this AppleScript to get a list of filenames for the master images

   ```
   set output_filename to "/Users/user/Pictures/album.txt"

   tell application "iPhoto"
       set pics to photos in current album
       do shell script "echo \"# Current album contents\" > " & output_filename
       repeat with pic in pics
           set picpath to image path of pic
           do shell script "echo " & picpath & " >> " & output_filename
       end repeat
   end tell
   ```
4. Using any text editor, save the script below to `update_pics.sh` and mark it executable (`chmod 755 update_pics.sh` on the command line)

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   # a quick script to parse in a series of filenames, and update them

   input_folder="$1"
   backup_folder="$2"

   if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
           echo "Usage: $0 [folder with new images] [folder for backups]"
           exit 0
   fi

   if [ ! -d "$input_folder" ]; then
           echo "Can't read input follder $input_folder"
           exit -1
   fi

   if [ ! -d "$backup_folder" ]; then
           mkdir -p "$backup_folder"
   fi

   if [ ! -d "$backup_folder" -o ! -w "$backup_folder" ]; then
           echo "Can't write to backup folder $backup_folder"
           exit -1
   fi

   while read line; do

           # skip empty lines or comments
           [ -z "$line" -o "${line:0:1}" = "#" ] && continue

           if [ -f "$line" ]; then
                   filename=`basename "$line"`
                   input_file="$input_folder/$filename"
                   cp "$line" "$backup_folder"
                   if [ -f "$input_file" ]; then
                           echo "Replacing $filename"
                           cp "$input_file" "$line"
                   else
                           echo "Could not find input file $input_file"
                   fi
           else
                   echo "$line does not exist"
           fi
   done
   ```
5. To use the script, give it the location of the updated pictures, a folder to put backups (I'm paranoid of losing data) and then pipe in the file generated before. For example:

   ```
   update_pics.sh Updates/ Backups/ < album.txt
   ```
6. If you haven't already, close iPhoto. Then restart it while holding down Option and Command. That should give you a dialog to rebuild the iPhoto. You should only need to rebuild the thumbnails, though you may want to rebuild everything else. [More info on rebuilding the iPhoto Library from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2638)

iPhoto will probably take a long time to rebuild the thumbnails, since it will redo *all* of them. You have a number of albums to do, it's probably best to update the pictures first, album-by-album, and then rebuild the library. That's what I did, and it worked pretty well.